# Speeding up boot process on a Debian server

Tags: debian, boot, performance

I run a Xeon server from Dell with SATA Samsung SSD 860 PRO.

I am looking for a way to speed up its boot time.

Is there a way for me to speed up boot time (`ssh` reachable time to be exact)?

I can see a monster time issue with `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`, is this it?

---

I made my **first measurement** using infinite loop:

```
$ date; while ! ssh-s -t date; do :; done
Wed 16 Mar 2022 08:50:54 AM CET
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.102 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.102 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.102 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.102 port 22: Connection timed out
Wed 16 Mar 2022 08:51:14 AM CET
Connection to 192.168.0.102 closed.
```

---

This is the **hardware**:

```
# inxi --verbosity 8 --filter
System:
  Kernel: 5.10.0-12-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-amd64 
  root=UUID=6eda9fbf-c86e-4e23-8587-427a06bae033 ro fsck.mode=auto fsck.repair=yes 
  ipv6.disable=1 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 tk: GTK 3.24.24 wm: Muffin 4.8.1 dm: LightDM 1.26.0 
  Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Dell product: PowerEdge T20 v: 00 serial: <filter> Chassis: 
  type: 6 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0VD5HY v: A04 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: A20 date: 08/20/2019 
Memory:
  RAM: total: 31.27 GiB used: 700.2 MiB (2.2%) 
  Array-1: capacity: 32 GiB slots: 4 EC: Single-bit ECC max module size: 8 GiB 
  note: est. 
  Device-1: DIMM3 size: 8 GiB speed: 1600 MT/s type: DDR3 detail: synchronous 
  bus width: 64 bits total: 72 bits manufacturer: Micron part-no: 18KSF1G72AZ-1G6E1 
  serial: <filter> 
  Device-2: DIMM1 size: 8 GiB speed: 1600 MT/s type: DDR3 detail: synchronous 
  bus width: 64 bits total: 72 bits manufacturer: Micron part-no: 18KSF1G72AZ-1G6E1 
  serial: <filter> 
  Device-3: DIMM4 size: 8 GiB speed: 1600 MT/s type: DDR3 detail: synchronous 
  bus width: 64 bits total: 72 bits manufacturer: Micron part-no: 18KSF1G72AZ-1G6E1 
  serial: <filter> 
  Device-4: DIMM2 size: 8 GiB speed: 1600 MT/s type: DDR3 detail: synchronous 
  bus width: 64 bits total: 72 bits manufacturer: Micron part-no: 18KSF1G72AZ-1G6E1 
  serial: <filter> 
PCI Slots:
  Slot: 1 type: x16 PCI Express 3 x16 X16 status: Available length: Long 
  Slot: 2 type: x1 PCI Express 2 x1 X1 status: In Use length: Short 
  Slot: 3 type: 32-bit PCI PCI status: Available length: Short 
  Slot: 4 type: x4 PCI Express 2 x4 X4 status: Available length: Short 
CPU:
  Info: Quad Core model: Intel Xeon E3-1225 v3 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Haswell 
  family: 6 model-id: 3C (60) stepping: 3 microcode: 28 L1 cache: 256 KiB 
  L2 cache: 8 MiB L3 cache: 7.8 MiB bogomips: 25539 
  Speed: 866 MHz min/max: 800/3600 MHz base/boost: 3200/3800 volts: 1.2 V 
  ext-clock: 100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 866 2: 832 3: 851 4: 846 
  Flags: abm acpi aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon avx avx2 bmi1 bmi2 bts clflush 
  cmov constant_tsc cpuid cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts epb ept 
  ept_ad erms est f16c flexpriority flush_l1d fma fpu fsgsbase fxsr ht ibpb ibrs ida 
  invpcid invpcid_single lahf_lm lm mca mce md_clear mmx monitor movbe msr mtrr 
  nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat pbe pcid pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs pge pln pni popcnt 
  pse pse36 pti pts rdrand rdtscp rep_good sdbg sep smep smx ss ssbd sse sse2 sse4_1 
  sse4_2 ssse3 stibp syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_adjust tsc_deadline_timer vme 
  vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xsave xsaveopt xtopology xtpr 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled 
  Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT disabled 
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled 
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
  Type: spec_store_bypass 
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 
  mitigation: Retpolines, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3 Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: Dell 
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:041a class ID: 0300 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  display ID: localhost:10.0 screens: 1 
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3840x2160 s-dpi: 48 s-size: 2032x1143mm (80.0x45.0") 
  s-diag: 2331mm (91.8") 
  Monitor-1: eDP-1-1 res: 3840x2160 hz: 60 dpi: 283 size: 345x194mm (13.6x7.6") 
  diag: 396mm (15.6") 
  OpenGL: renderer: N/A v: N/A direct render: N/A 
Audio:
  Message: No Device data found. 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I217-LM vendor: Dell driver: e1000e v: kernel port: f080 
  bus ID: 00:19.0 chip ID: 8086:153a class ID: 0200 
  IF: eth0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  IP v4: <filter> type: noprefixroute scope: global broadcast: <filter> 
  WAN IP: <filter> 
Bluetooth:
  Message: No Bluetooth data was found. 
Logical:
  Message: No LVM data was found. 
RAID:
  Message: No RAID data was found. 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 9.23 GiB (3.9%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 PRO 256GB 
  family: based SSDs size: 238.47 GiB block size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B 
  sata: 3.1 speed: 6.0 Gb/s rotation: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 2B6Q temp: 23 C 
  scheme: GPT 
  SMART: yes state: enabled health: PASSED on: 1y 25d 1h cycles: 1044 
  written: 3.77 TiB 
  Message: No Optical or Floppy data was found. 
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw size: 237.97 GiB size: 234.11 GiB (98.38%) used: 9.22 GiB (3.9%) 
  fs: ext4 block size: 4096 B dev: /dev/sda2 maj-min: 8:2 label: N/A 
  uuid: 6eda9fbf-c86e-4e23-8587-427a06bae033 
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw size: 512 MiB size: 511 MiB (99.80%) used: 3.4 MiB (0.7%) 
  fs: vfat block size: 512 B dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1 label: N/A uuid: 22B0-57B9 
Swap:
  Alert: No Swap data was found. 
Unmounted:
  Message: No Unmounted partitions found. 
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 3 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s 
  chip ID: 1d6b:0002 class ID: 0900 
  Hub-2: 1-1:2 info: Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub ports: 6 rev: 2.0 
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip ID: 8087:8008 class ID: 0900 
  Hub-3: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 15 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s 
  chip ID: 1d6b:0002 class ID: 0900 
  Hub-4: 3-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 3 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s 
  chip ID: 1d6b:0002 class ID: 0900 
  Hub-5: 3-1:2 info: Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub ports: 8 rev: 2.0 
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip ID: 8087:8000 class ID: 0900 
  Hub-6: 4-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 6 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s 
  chip ID: 1d6b:0003 class ID: 0900 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:
  Packages: 2134 apt: 2131 lib: 1242 flatpak: 3 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
  1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
  2: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
  3: deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
  4: deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list 
  1: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list 
Processes:
  CPU top: 5 of 153 
  1: cpu: 0.3% command: init pid: 1 mem: 10.3 MiB (0.0%) 
  2: cpu: 0.1% command: lightdm-gtk-greeter pid: 606 mem: 68.9 MiB (0.2%) 
  3: cpu: 0.0% command: [kthreadd] pid: 2 mem: 0.00 MiB (0.0%) 
  4: cpu: 0.0% command: [rcu_gp] pid: 3 mem: 0.00 MiB (0.0%) 
  5: cpu: 0.0% command: [rcu_par_gp] pid: 4 mem: 0.00 MiB (0.0%) 
  Memory top: 5 of 153 
  1: mem: 68.9 MiB (0.2%) command: lightdm-gtk-greeter pid: 606 cpu: 0.1% 
  2: mem: 44.2 MiB (0.1%) command: xorg pid: 556 cpu: 0.0% 
  3: mem: 37.3 MiB (0.1%) command: goa-daemon pid: 669 cpu: 0.0% 
  4: mem: 26.2 MiB (0.0%) command: tracker-miner-fs pid: 605 cpu: 0.0% 
  5: mem: 17.4 MiB (0.0%) command: systemd-journald pid: 253 cpu: 0.0% 
Info:
  Processes: 153 Uptime: 6m wakeups: 0 Init: systemd v: 247 runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
  gcc: 10.2.1 alt: 10/4.9/6/8 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 running in: sshd (SSH) inxi: 3.3.01
```

---

**`dmesg`** first + last line:

```
[Wed Mar 16 08:51:06 2022] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x28, date = 2019-11-12
...
[Wed Mar 16 08:51:12 2022] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

---

**`systemd-analyze`**:

```
# systemd-analyze blame 
3.163s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 406ms netfilter-persistent.service
 240ms dev-sda2.device
 176ms systemd-journal-flush.service
 115ms udisks2.service
 103ms exim4.service
 102ms user@117.service
 101ms accounts-daemon.service
  93ms apparmor.service
  85ms e2scrub_reap.service
  83ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  82ms boot-efi.mount
  80ms keyboard-setup.service
  76ms plymouth-start.service
  75ms upower.service
  70ms user@0.service
  66ms smartmontools.service
  61ms systemd-journald.service
  52ms avahi-daemon.service
  51ms systemd-logind.service
  49ms ifupdown-pre.service
  45ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  41ms wpa_supplicant.service
  38ms lightdm.service
  34ms NetworkManager.service
  32ms networking.service
  32ms systemd-udevd.service
  31ms run-rpc_pipefs.mount
  29ms ssh.service
  21ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  21ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-22B0\x2d57B9.service
  21ms lm-sensors.service
  19ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  16ms systemd-modules-load.service
  15ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  15ms rsyslog.service
  12ms polkit.service
  12ms atd.service
  11ms modprobe@configfs.service
  11ms rpcbind.service
  11ms dev-hugepages.mount
  11ms plymouth-read-write.service
  11ms dev-mqueue.mount
  11ms systemd-sysusers.service
  10ms modprobe@fuse.service
  10ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   9ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   9ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   9ms systemd-random-seed.service
   9ms gdomap.service
   8ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   8ms systemd-sysctl.service
   7ms modprobe@drm.service
   7ms user-runtime-dir@0.service
   7ms user-runtime-dir@117.service
   6ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   5ms nfs-config.service
   5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   4ms console-setup.service
   4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   1ms rc-local.service
   1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

- 

```
# systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @4.307s
└─multi-user.target @4.307s
  └─exim4.service @4.204s +103ms
    └─network-online.target @4.203s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.040s +3.163s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.004s +34ms
          └─network-pre.target @1.004s
            └─netfilter-persistent.service @597ms +406ms
              └─local-fs.target @595ms
                └─run-user-117-gvfs.mount @1.544s
                  └─run-user-117.mount @1.373s
                    └─local-fs-pre.target @314ms
                      └─keyboard-setup.service @234ms +80ms
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @230ms
                          └─system.slice @181ms
                            └─-.slice @181ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a total boot time of about 20 seconds, out of which about 6 seconds is kernel/OS start-up before the NIC comes up, and 2 more seconds for starting the network services after the NIC has been activated.

That leaves the firmware and bootloader as the largest single component, with a total of 12 seconds. You might want to check the firmware settings (BIOS/UEFI settings) to ensure any memory tests etc. are skipped or are performed as quickly as possible.

Your "monster time issue with `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`" is only about 3 or 4 seconds.

You might want to add `e1000e` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and run `update-initramfs -u` as root after it to ensure that the NIC driver module is loaded as early as possible. You'll also want to get any Energy-Efficient Ethernet (EEE) or other power saving features in the network switch port for your system switched off, if possible: that should simplify & speed up the start-up of the physical network connection.